# Angular internalization translate file upload button text

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular-i18n

I am using Angular and `i18n` to translate the applications in different languages.

How to translate the input file upload button choose file and No file chosen text.

```
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader] = "uploader">
```

[ng2-file-upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYryd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like this:

You can create custom file upload using traditional so you can use `Angular internalization translate`.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbuqqk)

HTML:

```
<label class="custom-file-upload">
            <input #fileInput  type="file" (change)="select($event)" />
            <span i18n>Upload File</span>
        </label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    a {
        color: #0000ee;
    }

    a:hover {
        color: #0000ee;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}
```

TS:

```
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: any;
  select(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is quite old question however i will answer it as i just faced the same scenario.
p-upload allow you to set choose label like `chooseLabel="Choose"` 
then you can apply your localization in this way

`chooseLabel="{{ 'Choose' | localize }}"`

as shown in official documentation
https://primeng.org/fileupload